# UWP: Trimming the text of a TextBlock based on number of lines

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an UWP application where I want to trim the text of the `TextBlock` if it goes beyond the third line and show "show more" link (tappable) in the end of the 3rd line.

I know to restrict number of lines I can use `MaxLines` property but it simply ignores the rest of the lines as if they don't exist. But I want to let the user know that there is some more text and he can tap on the show more link to navigate to the full text.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [good topic](http://blog.damiendelaire.com/2015/12/creating-expandable-textblock-control.html) which describes all step to create an expandable textblock

Also, view the source code on [github](https://github.com/Delaire/Samples)

Here is the XAML code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Tapped="LayoutRoot_OnTap">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                  x:Name= "CommentTextBlock"
                  HorizontalAlignment= "Left"
                  TextWrapping= "Wrap"
                  Height= "Auto"
                  Width= "280" />

      < StackPanel Grid.Row= "1"
                  Orientation= "Horizontal"
                  HorizontalAlignment= "Right"
                  x:Name= "ExpandHint"
                  Visibility= "Collapsed"
                  Margin= "0,5,0,0" >
          < TextBlock  Text= "View More" />
           < TextBlock Margin= "10,0,10,0"
        Text= "+" />
      </ StackPanel >
</ Grid >
```

Here is C# part

```
public sealed partial class ExpandableTextBlock : UserControl
{
   public ExpandableTextBlock()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(ExpandableTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnTextChanged));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = (ExpandableTextBlock)d;
        ctl.CommentTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, (string)e.NewValue);
        ctl.CommentTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.HeightProperty, Double.NaN);

        ctl.CommentTextBlock.Measure(new Size(ctl.CommentTextBlock.Width, double.MaxValue));

        double desiredheight = ctl.CommentTextBlock.DesiredSize.Height;
        ctl.CommentTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.HeightProperty, (double)63);

        if (desiredheight > (double)ctl.CommentTextBlock.GetValue(TextBlock.HeightProperty))
        {
            ctl.ExpandHint.SetValue(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);
            ctl.MaxHeight = desiredheight;
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.ExpandHint.SetValue(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
        }

        //Setting length of comments
        var boundsWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        ctl.CommentTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.WidthProperty, boundsWidth);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollapsedHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CollapsedHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ExpandableTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(default(double), OnCollapsedHeightChanged));


    public double CollapsedHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CollapsedHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CollapsedHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnCollapsedHeightChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = (ExpandableTextBlock)d;
        ctl.CollapsedHeight = (double)e.NewValue;
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "TextStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(ExpandableTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(default(Style), OnTextStyleChanged));

    public Style TextStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(TextStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnTextStyleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = (ExpandableTextBlock)d;
        ctl.CommentTextBlock.SetValue(StyleProperty, (Style)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void LayoutRoot_OnTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs tappedRoutedEventArgs)
    {
       if ((Visibility)this.ExpandHint.GetValue(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty) == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            //transition
            this.CommentTextBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.HeightProperty, Double.NaN);

            this.ExpandHint.SetValue(StackPanel.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the essential parts here in case the link gets broken. You can keep the links as reference of course.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka I am having issues with the fixed width of the CommentTextBlock. As I said, I have a UWP application so on desktop, if I resize the window to make it narrow, the text block would cut off the string since the width of CommentTextBlock would be set to the size of the window of the wider screen. How can I fix the width?